# Remove space between scrolling on homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, whitespace

I'm trying to remove the spaces on a site, what appears on the top when scrolling.

You can see it here: http://waterwise.bemediadev.com.au/

When you scroll down, a white stripe appears, and I can't seem to make it disappear.

There is no padding or anything set up!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have padding in each section

```
padding-bottom:78px;
```

you need to clear that i think there is somewhere the option where you can make that in themify builder as i have not used that builder

Comment: thank you very much, you are right I see it, but there is no padding set in the builder, so i don't know where could i change it. I am looking for a CSS class, that i can maybe add in the theme, to override this, but i can't find that either.

Comment: I fixed it by adding this

.themify_builder_5_row{
padding-bottom: 0.1px !important;
}

Thank you!